# Problem when printing array using only pointers

Tags: c, function-declaration

I need  a function for putting `int` values in an array and another function for printing it only using pointers,  but I have a problem when printing the values.

Here is the code :
[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void remplir(int *t,int n){
int i,*p;
p=t;
for(p=t;p<t+n;p++){
    printf("remplir la case numero : %d \n ",i);
    scanf("%d",p);
}
}
void afficher(t,n){
int *p;
for(p=t;p<t+n;p++){
    printf("%d",*p);
}
}
int main()
{
int n,t[50],*p;
printf("donner la taille ");
scanf("%d",&n);
remplir(t,n);
afficher(t,n);
}
```

Comment: problem in printing the values from the array like in the picture dude , if you need more details im here  i hope you understund my bad english

Comment: First set `i=0`.  Then change `i` to `i++`

Comment: im obligied to do everything in pointers

Comment: "I have a problem" -> *What* problem? Do you get a specific error message? Does the program just stop running and return you the command prompt? Does it overwrite your hard disk and email your banking details to haxors?

Comment: The problem was you were not specifying the types of the arguments to `afficher` and so C can't tell you what was going wrong.  The type system exists to help you track down errors (and other things).  You should enable more of your compiler warnings and use a newer C standard to prevent problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

You declared this function incorrectly

```
void afficher(t,n){
```

It seems you mean

```
void afficher( int *t, int n){
```

It would be even better to declare and define the function like

```
void afficher( const int a[], int n )
{
    if ( 0 < n )
    {
        for ( const int *p = a; p != a + n; p++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", *p );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

or

```
void afficher( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    for ( const int *p = a; p != a + n; p++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", *p );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Comment: when i added a  * like you said it says : "unknow type name 'n' in the same line

Comment: @maxel Try to copy and paste.

Comment: it works =) im going to figure it out what's wrong thanks a lot mate .